# rtl100.bpl was not found?

Tags: delphi, bpl

I am learning a component from TMS. I got "...rtl100.bpl was not found...". probably this error was happened if I use "Build with runtime packages" that contains "rtl".

Where is rtl100.bpl (I am using D2007)? What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: @KenWhite, The tag rtl is for "Register-Transfer-Level". %95 percent of the miss use of the rtl tag meant "right-to-left". Thanks for the info, I'll be more careful with future corrections.

Comment: @Greg: No problem. :-) The "right-to-left" didn't apply either. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi 2006 and Delphi 2007 both come with rtl100.bpl. You can normally find it in your %system32% folder. You should have this dll installed on the machine where your application runs. You can install it alongside your exe or put it in a place where all applications can find it (Like %system32%). If you don't want your application to be dependable on this dll you should turn off "Build with runtime packages" in your project options.

Comment: I don't have rtl100.bpl in my %system32%. Did the file come with Delphi installation? I am following a tutorial so I don't want to turn off the option.